# strange characters key in Key topic

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I using this query to generate a table in KSQLDB

```
CREATE TABLE LimiteOneMinute_TB2
   WITH (kafka_topic='limitoneminute2', value_format='JSON') as
select (lr.rowkey) majmoo , AS_VALUE(cast(lr.rowkey as varchar)) inet_config, max(lr.inet) ip, (max(lr.rowtime) + 60000) expire_time, true as captcha
from LIMITER_REQUEST lr join CONFIG_TB lc on lr.configid = lc.id
WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 59 SECONDS, ADVANCE BY 5 SECONDS)
group by (lr.rowkey)
having count(*) > max(lc.oneminute)
emit changes;
```

After running it, I saw output (limitoneminute2 topic) and I have a problem with Key.

What are these extra characters?
How can I clean them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create a windowed aggregation (as you are doing) the window forms part of the key. So what you are seeing in **key** is a representation of the `GROUP BY` key, plus the window's start and end times.

To "clean" the key would not make sense in this context, because then you would have a single key per aggregate and no time windows.

Comment: thanks. I want to find these events by key so I need to know the exact key of each event in this topic (for example compact topic). What way do you suggest?

Comment: What are you consuming them with? Unless something's changed I don't think the topic keys are designed to be consumed directly, but instead you should use a query from within ksqlDB (e.g. using the REST API) from your application.